# Dict to DataFrame with keys as column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dictionary with different length of values:

```
d = {'A': [1,1,1], 'B': [2], 'C': [3,3,3]}
```

How to turn it to dataframe, where keys are first column and values are second column?

```
clm1    clm2
A       1
A       1
A       1
B       2
C       3
C       3
C       3
```

I tried `pd.DataFrame.to_dict` with `orint='index'`, but didn't get the desired result.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flatten values in list comprehension for list of tuples and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(a,c) for a, b in d.items() for c in b], columns=['clm1','clm2'])
print (df)
  clm1  clm2
0    A     1
1    A     1
2    A     1
3    B     2
4    C     3
5    C     3
6    C     3
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest transforming your dict items to list then transform the obtained list to a dataframe with specifying the desired columns names

```
l=list(d.items())
df = pd.DataFrame(l,columns=['clm1','clm2'])
```

Comment: There should be a description for your answer as it helps both the OP and the future readers.